Linux server randomly loses connection for some seconds/minutes
I have a linux server running Ubuntu server 24.04 LTS. The server acts as a docker host and has around 40 containers running. On the host itself not much was changed after the initial Ubuntu installation. The server is connect directly to the router via ethernet.
Now I have the problem, that from time to time, the server loses all network connectivity for some seconds, sometimes even minutes. Then it is not pingable and ssh won't work as well. Also in the logs of the docker containers I can see timeouts and connection losses for every service connecting to the internet or other services in the network outside the host. The communication between the containers on the host seems to stay intact though. So far I was not able to recognise a pattern when the outages occur. Usually it happens only a few times a day. However when there is a lot of traffic on the connection, e.g. when server is uploading its backup to the backup location, it happens every 5 minutes or so.
Here is what I tried so far, all without success:

use a different machine to host the containers
use a different network cable
use a different router
use a different OS on the host (Debian 12)

I am totally lost on how to debug this further. Unfortunately I don't know much about networking on linux/docker. I am not even sure if it is related to Docker at all. Any advice on how to proceed or where to take a closer look would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I should provide more information.
Edit
When looking at the kernel logs when such a connection drop occurs I see this (I cut most of the error codes because I was hitting the max character count for this message):
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:40 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: NETDEV WATCHDOG: CPU: 6: transmit queue 0 timed out 5248 ms
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:40 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: transmit timed out, resetting
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:43 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00000000: 0x168614e4, 0x00100406, 0x02000001, 0x00800040
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:43 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00000010: 0xa040000c, 0x00000000, 0xa041000c, 0x00000000
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:43 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00000020: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x168614e4
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:43 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00000030: 0x00000000, 0x00000048, 0x00000000, 0x00000100
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:43 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00000040: 0x00000000, 0x90000000, 0xc8035001, 0x16002008
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:43 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00000050: 0x00005803, 0x00000000, 0x0086a005, 0x00000000
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:43 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00000060: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0xf0010298, 0x761b000f
...
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00007020: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000406, 0x10004000
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00007030: 0x00010000, 0x000000c8, 0x000c0030, 0x00000000
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0x00007500: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000080, 0x00000000
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0: Host status block [00000001:00000090:(0000:00d2:0000):(0000:01b3)]
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 0: NAPI info [00000090:00000090:(01a0:01b3:01ff):0000:(019a:0000:0000:0000)]
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 1: Host status block [00000001:00000021:(0000:0000:0000):(00d3:0000)]
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 1: NAPI info [00000021:00000021:(0000:0000:01ff):00d3:(00d3:00d3:0000:0000)]
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 2: Host status block [00000001:000000f5:(03ff:0000:0000):(0000:0000)]
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: 2: NAPI info [000000f5:000000f5:(0000:0000:01ff):03ff:(01ff:01ff:0000:0000)]
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:44 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: Link is down
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:47 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:47 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[Wed Aug 14 06:19:47 2024] tg3 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0f0: EEE is enabled


Welcome! Lots of things might cause similar problems. First, it would be useful to know if your server's Ethernet connection is actually dropping. The next time you encounter one of these pauses, try running dmesg -T | tail as root (or sudo dmesg -T | tail if you have sudo privileges). This will show you the 10 most recent kernel messages.
If the link is going down/up, you will see messages saying "NIC Link is Down" and "NIC Link is Up" in this output. You should also be able to provoke such messages by unplugging and replugging the Ethernet cable.

Thank you very much for your response. I did take a look at the kernel logs and can indeed see the "Link is down" and "Link is up" messages. I updated my question with the kernel logs for one connection drop from start to end. However, I had to cut most of the error codes (or whatever the hex numbers are). Otherwise my post would get too big. Do you have an idea on how to proceed?

What exactly do you mean with use a different OS on the host (Debian 12)? You reinstalled the machine with debian? Then installed Ubuntu 24.04 again when debian behaved the same?

Exactly. They both behaved the same way in regards to the network issue.

Thanks for including the dmesg -T output. That is a pretty strong clue. The fact that the link is going down/up and that changing router+cable made no difference suggests either a hardware issue with your NIC or a driver problem. After some searching, I lean towards the latter.
For future reference, lspci is a useful command to list your detected hardware. Running lspci | grep -i eth will generally tell you make/model of your network card. Your tg3 driver implies a Broadcom device.
There is apparently a known issue with the tg3 driver across a range of kernel versions that looks a lot like what you see. It seems to affect multiple OSes and multiple NIC models. The reports describe a transmit timeout, link down, then link up, like you observe.
I suggest reading through this and this. Also look at official bug reports here and here.
If this is indeed your problem, enabling IOMMU passthrough seems to solve the problem (after a reboot). The exact syntax to use for this seems to vary with OS, but several methods are explained in the links above. Hopefully this helps, good luck!

Thank you very much for your detailed response. I also did some searching yesterday after seeing the kernel logs and found this thread: link. That also suggested to enable IOMMU passthrough. Which I did yesterday and can now report that I had not had a single connection drop within 24 hours. I hope it stays that way. Thanks again for your tip with the kernel logs. I definitely learned something new :)
